# Consuming a USB HID device in Windows CE 6.0 using C#

Tags: c#, embedded, usb, windows-ce, hid

I am working on an embedded [Windows CE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_CE) project and am interested in accessing a USB HID device through one of its USB Host ports. All I really need to read are the raw HID specification packets.

On a Windows computer, I have a working program using hid.dll, but as far as I have researched, there isn't any equivalent on Windows CE. I know there is the *usbhid.dll* file, but I'm not sure if it is applicable for this situation. I would prefer not to write a kernel level driver, as I would like to do my coding in C#. How can I make consuming an HID device on Windows CE work?

Comment: If you have made any headway with this please let me know. I'm about to embark on writing a HiD driver for a bluetooth keyboard on the same platform. Would love a heads up development issues with Win CE as this will be my first ever compact framework development

Comment: Any progress with this? I'm trying to do the exact thing , but i cannot see the usb device as an serial port .

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't have much luck with this project, so I can't help very much. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no concrete experience with HID, but accessing the USB port as a COM port with a proper driver DLL (the device manufacturer might have one) might help. Theoretically you should be able to receive the device's raw data packets with a `SerialPort` class that way.

Answer (score 0):

Toradex released their USB sensors and peripherals as open source.

The sensors are HID devices and the freely available source code does include samples for C# and Visual Basic on Windows CE.

*[Oak Sensors and Interfaces](http://developer.toradex.com/oak-sensors-and-interfaces)*